# Handling "Internal Server Error" from Web Assembly

Tags: exception, webassembly, webapi

My app calls a Web Api to do a post.  The call to the API looks like this:

postResult = await client.PutAsJsonAsync("api/G_ValuationScenario", ValuationScenario_Singleton, JsonHelper.SerializationOptions);

And, in the Web API, this code is executed in the constructor:

this._context = context;

And, then still in the Web API, the Put is supposed to be executed:

[HttpPut]
public async Task Put(ValuationScenario ValuationScenario_Singleton)
{
_context.Entry(ValuationScenario_Singleton).State = EntityState.Modified;

However, by using the debugger, I can see that I execute the last line of the constructor but the Put is never called.

Again, using the debugger I can see that the postresult in the client's call contains "Internal Server Error" and no additional information that I can find.

What I am asking for:  Guidance on exception handling that I should include to make diagnosing this easier.

Btw, I did check event logs and have a problem with a depth (assuming on JSON) that exceeds 32 levels.  I thought I had that covered but can figure that one out.  Looking for best practices on how to handle this error.